# Compilation error 800A0401

Tags: vbscript

**I have recently been searching for a solution to my problem and I came across this website. I attempted to follow instructions on how to fix my problem from many other sites but I'm not entirely good at this sort of thing.... Here is my problem:**

Windows Script Host
Script: C:\Documents and Settings\Me\Application Data\bits2\windows.vbs
Line: 33
Char: 428
Error: Expected end of statement
Code: 800A0401
Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error

**I found the script and noticed that line 33 does not have 428 characters in it so I am now really stuck on what to do...... Here is the whole script:**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions                                                                                                                                                               &n bsp;                                                                                                                                                                &nb sp;                                                                  Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
```

**I hope you can help, thank you.**

Comment: line 9 looks wrong `objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")`. copy 'n paste error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7308287/69820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> line 33 does not have 428 characters in it

It actually has 483 characters, and isn't valid:

```
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions                                                                                                                                                               &n bsp;                                                                                                                                                                &nb sp;                                                                  Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
```