# Run time error 800A01A8

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error

**I am terribly stuck right now! Can someone please help?! This is the message I keep getting:**

Windows Script Host
Script: C:\Documents and Settings\Me\Application Data\bits2\windows.vbs
Line: 9
Char: 1
Error: Object required: 'intOptionsSet'
Code: 800A01A8
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

**Here is my script:**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder)
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
```

Comment: Did you take a close look at line 9 with objTarget.CopyHere?  Looks like there might be a partial line of code combined with another line there.

Comment: The answer probably has it.  But I'm just confused about this code. Why do you have the same code repeated 22 times?

Answer (score 0):

That looks mangled ... this;

```
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
```

Is probably supposed to be:

```
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptions
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
```

You probably only need the latter line once, rather than all the repeats you have.

**Edit;** That also appears just to be a repetition of the fist 9 lines?

Answer (score 0):

**`objShell.NameSpace()` does not like 2 backslashes next to each other, i.e. c:\\**

*(unless it's a network path, i.e. \\192.168.0.1\Folder)*

The first 9 lines of your code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
appdata= WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
strZipFile = appdata & "\bits2\file.zip"
outFolder = appdata & "\bits2" 'Line #4
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objSource = objShell.NameSpace(strZipFile).Items()
Set objTarget = objShell.NameSpace(outFolder) 'Line #7
intOptions = 256
objTarget.CopyHere objSource, intOptionsSet. WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 'Line #9
```

Maybe line #9 is blowing up because `outFolder` on line #7 has ":\\" in it.  `outFolder` is defined on line #4.